# Data structures for audio editor

Tags: data-structures, audio, editor, editing

I have been writing an audio editor for the last couple of months, and have been recently thinking about how to implement fast and efficient editing (cut, copy, paste, trim, mute, etc.). There doesn't really seem to be very much information available on this topic, however... I know that Audacity, for example, uses a block file strategy, in which the sample data (and summaries of that data, used for efficient waveform drawing) is stored on disk in fixed-sized chunks. What other strategies might be possible, however? There is quite a lot of info on data-structures for text editing - many text (and hex) editors appear to use the piece-chain method, nicely described [here](http://catch22.net/tuts/neatpad/17) - but could that, or something similar, work for an audio editor?

Many thanks in advance for any thoughts, suggestions, etc.
Chris

Answer (score 0):

the classical problem for editors handling relative large files is how to cope with deletion and insertion. Text editors obviously face this, as typically the user enters characters one at a time. Audio editors don't typically do "sample by sample" inserts, i.e. the user doesn't interactively enter one sample per time, but you have some cut-and-paste operations. I would start with a representation where an audio file is represented by chunks of data which are stored in a (binary) search tree. Insert works by splitting the chunk you are inserting into two chunks, adding the inserted chunk as a third one, and updating the tree. To make this efficient and responsive to the user, you should then have a background process that defragments the representation on disk (or in memory) and then makes an atomic update to the tree holding the chunks. This should make inserts and deletes as fast as possible. Many other audio operations (effects, normalize, mix) operate in-place and do not require changes to the data structure, but doing e.g. normalize on the whole audio sample is a good opportunity to defragment it at the same time. If the audio samples are large, you can keep the chunks as it is standard on hard disk also. I don't believe the chunks need to be fixed size; they can be variable size, preferably 1024 x (power of two) bytes to make file operations efficient, but a fixed-size strategy can be easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Antti. In fact I have been investigating some kind of binary search tree as a possible solution. It seems that a number of text editors adopt this strategy (for example Abiword), though I'm still rather doubtful that many audio editors use this method. I'm basically trying to establish what 'best practice' is in this area, before diving in.